# OpenGL Throws Exception When Drawing Basic Line

Tags: java, exception, opengl, line

I can draw about every shape you can think of without getting errors, but as soon as I draw a line it throws an exception at *GL11.glEnd()*

```
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GL11.glLineWidth(1);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINE);
    {
        GL11.glVertex2i(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(5, 5);
    }
    GL11.glEnd(); // Exception Here
```

The Exception: *"OpenGLException: Invalid enum (1280)"*
Does anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_LINE` is not a valid primitive type, `GL_LINES` is  what you are looking for...

Comment: Worked! Will mark as answer as soon as it allows me! I am trusting too much on the auto complete feature. :P